# Kicking a process from a USB-Serial port

Tags: usb, serial-port, serial-console

I have a application which is using the USB-serial port.  Occasionally on shutdown the port cannot be opened by another instance of the program, and up until now the only way I know of the program being able to access it again is through reboot.This is undesirable

How to I regain control of the USB-serial port? Either by unlocking it,(marking is as unused) or by killing all processes using it?

Comment: Presuming your serial device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`, what does `lsof | grep ttyUSB0` say when the device is in this state? (You may have to run this as root.)

Comment: This is OS-dependent. Linux? FreeBSD? MINIX? AIX? …

Comment: linux, specifically suse 11.4. lsof | grep ttyUSB0 gave me nothing. I could see the program using it when it was activated, but killing processes did nothing to affect behavior